# HTC Sensation not displaying app in full screen

Tags: android, android-screen

When I install my app on HTC Sensation, it does not display full screen.
After reading http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html, I have tried using both :

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11"
```

and also tried adding:

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

That is:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
/>
```

However, these do not seem to work.

I also installed Spare Parts and used it to disable Screen Compatability Mode, but this did n't work either. In fact, this app seemed to display the same issue also !

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, with HTC Sensation

i had in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

and i changed to (**and helped it**).

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

but i try also this (and works too).

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"/>
```

i hope, this also help to you.

Answer (score 0):

do you want your app to be displayed in full screen mode? If yes then put this code in your manifest on the activity you want to be displayed in full screen:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid it didn't work. I think is has something to do with the fact that it has a qhd screen.

Comment: It seems that you are right.. the problem comes from the "unique" screen. I will try to research a bit more the problem and get back with a post if I have something..

Comment: Please try this too <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" /> I know you already set the min sdk and the target one but please put these values :)